# How to prevent an image from panning beyond the image frame (or screen)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

If you have played around with Apple's Room Tutorial (link: [../WWDC2019/204/](http://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/204)), I added a small touch-to-zoom gesture (thanks to @Alladinian and brar07), per the code below.

HOWEVER, the image when touched and panned, moves off the screen and does not return to its original position. *You should be able to copy+paste this code into Apple's project with little modifications*.

**REQUIREMENTS**: **1)** The image should stay within the confines of the image frame, i.e. when zoomed, the edges of the image should not go beyond the edges of the defined frame (or screen if the frame is not defined). **2)** The image should return to its original position.

*This final result would be similar to how mouse-over works for product images on some websites*.

```
import SwiftUI


struct RoomDetail: View {

    let room : Room

    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var isTouchingScreen = false
    @State var isZoomedIn = false
    @State var pointTouchedOnScreen: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    @State var panSize: CGSize = CGSize.zero
    @State var fingerState: String = "Finger is not touching the image"

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            // Show the room selected by the user, implement zooming capabilities
            GeometryReader { reader in

                Image("\(self.room.name)" + "_Thumb")
                    .resizable()
                    .offset(x: self.panSize.width, y: self.panSize.height)
                    .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)

                        .onChanged {  (value) in

                            self.fingerState = "Finger is touching the image" // for debug purpose only

                            self.isZoomedIn = true

                            self.isTouchingScreen = true

                            self.pointTouchedOnScreen = value.startLocation

                            self.scale = 1.1


                            let offsetWidth = (reader.frame(in: .global).maxX * self.scale - reader.frame(in: .global).maxX) / 2

                            let newDraggedWidth = self.panSize.width * self.scale

                            if (newDraggedWidth > offsetWidth) {
                                self.panSize = CGSize(width: (value.translation.width + self.panSize.width), height: (value.translation.height + self.panSize.height))
                            } else if (newDraggedWidth <  -offsetWidth) {
                                self.panSize = CGSize(width: (value.translation.width + self.panSize.width), height: (value.translation.height + self.panSize.height))
                            } else {
                                self.panSize = CGSize(width: (value.translation.width + self.panSize.width), height: (value.translation.height + self.panSize.height))
                            }
                    }

                    .onEnded { _ in

                        self.fingerState = "Finger is not touching the image" // for debug purpose only

                        self.isZoomedIn = false

                        self.isTouchingScreen = false


                    })
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: self.isZoomedIn ? .fill : .fit)
                        .scaleEffect(self.isTouchingScreen ? self.scale : 1, anchor: UnitPoint(x: self.pointTouchedOnScreen.x / reader.frame(in: .global).maxX, y: self.pointTouchedOnScreen.y / reader.frame(in: .global).maxY))
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
                        .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 50, maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 200, alignment: .center)
                        .clipped()
                        .offset(x: 0, y: -50)
        }
    }
}

struct RoomDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RoomDetail(room: testData[0])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if this answers your question exactly, but I wanted to make this note:

- The ORDER of modifiers MATTERS
- I was trying to do a zoom effect and
  it kept exceeding the frame of the image
- However, when I set the FRAME AFTER the scale effect, it stayed within the bounds

This didn't work, the image wouldn't "crop" to the size of the frame for the image:

```
Image(uiImage: self.userData.image!)
.resizable()
.offset(x: self.currentPosition.width, y: self.currentPosition.height)
.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
.frame(maxWidth:metrics.size.width * 0.60, maxHeight: metrics.size.height * 0.60, alignment: .top)
.scaleEffect(self.scale)
.clipped()
.foregroundColor(.gray)
```

Whereas this DID work:

```
Image(uiImage: self.userData.image!)
.resizable()
.scaleEffect(self.scale)
.offset(x: self.currentPosition.width, y: self.currentPosition.height)
.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
.frame(maxWidth:metrics.size.width * 0.60, maxHeight: metrics.size.height * 0.60, alignment: .top)  
.clipped()
.foregroundColor(.gray)
```

The only difference being applying the scaleEffect before the frame. (In this case, I have a drag gesture and a zoom gesture).

Spent a lot of time trying to sort this out and not sure it exactly solves your issue but perhaps useful to someone.